# "whatever" as pure determiner?

Tags: grammaticality, determiners, relative-pronouns

My dictionaries and references define, and I've always thought of, one of the functions of the word *whatever* as a "relative determiner."

In a sentence like, *"I will help you in whatever way is possible,"*  inserting the relative pronoun *"that"* between *"way"* and  *"is"*, or replacing *"whatever"* with *"the"* - a pure, non-relative determiner - (I reckon) renders it ungrammatical:

> *I will help you in whatever way that is possible.
>   *I will help you in the way is possible.

However, I do often encounter utterances like the first one above, such as:

> My hope and intent is to contribute in whatever way that I can.
>   I wish to be of service to the local communities in whatever way that is possible.

where *"that"* is used, and thus *"whatever"* can be replaced by *"the"* without  making the sentences ungrammatical (if they are grammatical to begin with):

> My hope and intent is to contribute in **the** way that I can.
>   I wish to be of service to the local communities in **the** way that is possible.

Is this usage of *"that"* with *"whatever"* wrong, though colloquial?

Comment: Great question. How would you interpret: "My hope is to contribute in whatever/the way I can"? Sounds correct to my ear when you substitute "the" for "what," even without "that." I think the distinction is the presence of the subject (of the clause) *I*. Perhaps that one example is different from the others.

Comment: `I will help you in whatever way that is possible.` As an editor, I would never let that stand. I would change it to something like `I will help you in any way possible.` "That" has no place in there.

Comment: @Ricky Whats wrong with using `that` ? It can be ommitted, but using it is still correct english.

Comment: @123: That would be true (no pun intended) if the OP were using "any" instead of "whatever."  "Whatever way that is possible" is nonsense. "Do whatever that you like."

Comment: @Ricky Those sentences can't be substituted with `any` instead though. `I'll help in whatever way that i can` sounds okay to because `any` can be subbed in.

Comment: @123: I have no idea what you just said, but I insist that "whatever" and "that" should never be separated by fewer than seven words.

Comment: @Ricky Not sure what authority you are on the English language to insist anything but whatever. Also don't understand how you can't understand my previous comment. In your sentences substituting `any` for `whatever`, would make the sentences make no sense i.e `"Do any that you like."`. Whereas in OP's and mine it still would i.e `I'll help in any way that i can`

Comment: @123: "In any way that I can" sounds pretty horrible too.

Comment: @Ricky I disagree and you haven't provided any real reasons why it shouldn't be used other than your opinion that it `sounds pretty horrible` so continuing this conversation is pretty pointless. Lets just disagree :)

Comment: @123: I agree to disagree. Actually, "sounds pretty horrible" and "sounds okay" predate rules and grammar books. The vast majority of the rules are in fact based on "sounds awful" and "sounds beautiful." I have no idea what subjunctive means. The word scares the hell out of me each time I see it. I do find a measure of solace in the fact that Shakespeare had no clue what it means either.

Comment: @Ricky - *"whatever" and "that" should never be separated by fewer than seven words* !  Sounds like you're shooting from the hip - is it true?

Comment: @Dan:  Well, ten is better if you ask me. Seven would be pushing it.

Comment: *Whatever you say, that will be how it is.* ?

Comment: @Dan `He said he was okay, whatever that means`

Comment: Nice one!  *He said that, whatever 'that' means!* Good game!

Comment: *"That 'that' that that man said means whatever that 'that' that that man said meant to him"*.   I must get on!

Comment: Replace "whatever" with "any" and see if it "makes sense".  If so then there's no problem, since "whatever" essentially means "any" and functions (in the above examples) as the same part of speech.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using 'in whatever way possible' rather than 'in whatever way that I can', so I looked it up.  https://edtrust.org/the-equity-line/finding-success-in-whatever-way-possible/
Apparently New Zealand likes the expression.